# Sencha cmd, closure compiler error: how to locate the offending code

Tags: javascript, extjs, google-closure-compiler, sencha-cmd

When running Sencha cmd 6.5, and I get the following error:

> [ERR] C2001: Closure Compiler Error (Parse error. undefined label "f") -- compression-input:1:4095

How can I locate the code at `compression-input:1:4095` ?

This happens when I include a custom javascript file in `app.json` using:

```
"js": [
    {
        "path": "app.js",
        "bundle": true
    },{
        "path": "custom.js",
        "includeInBundle": true
    }
],
```

The error disapears when I remove the reference to `custom.js` in `app.json`.

If I interpret the error correctly, it means that closure compiler finds an error on line 1, character 4095 of the `compression-input`. But the first line of `custom.js` is not such long.

How can I locate the offending code ?

And by the way, what is an `undefined label` in closure compiler ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue a year ago, and I was told you cannot locate it from the error message.

Assuming that you have already tried to open your uncompiled project directly in the browser, and not getting a syntax error, there's not much you can do except narrowing it down further by splitting the custom.js content in two parts and check these independently.

In my case it was `Ext.define` where should have been `Ext.create`, and the syntax error is thrown because usage of `Ext.define` is rewritten into other commands during generation of the `compression-input`. Maybe if you look for this specifically, you can find it.

Answer (score 2):

With Sencha Cmd 7.7.0 (at least) you can do:

```
sencha compile concatenate --input-js-version ANY --js-version ANY --output-file all.js
```

Followed by:

```
closure-compiler --js all.js --js_output_file out.js
```

To get a good error message:

```
all.js:418012:59: ERROR - [JSC_PARSE_ERROR] Parse error. invalid arrow function parameters
  418012|         const focusedRowIndex = currentRowElements.flatMap([index,item] => item.id === focusedRow.id ? parseInt(index) : []).pop();
```

Install `closure-compiler` from your package manager `brew` or `choco`...

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problems too.
I disabled compression in app.json file:

```
"testing": {
   "compressor": {
     //"type": "closure",
     "type": "none",
     "warningLevel": "quiet"
   },
   "output": "...."
}
```

And I separately checked the output app.js file with the compiler (which can be downloaded):

```
java -jar closure-compiler-v20210302.jar --js app.js --js_output_file compiled_output.js
```